# Images appear in Chrome, but not in IE

Tags: html, image, web

Was handed this little gem of a site this morning. The site works great in Chrome, but IE9 seems a bit buggy.

The banner and 4 link buttons somehow "vanish" when viewed in IE9. They appear breifly, for a second, and then POOF! Gone!

Located here:
http://www.cityplaceselfstorage.com/Calidus/calidus.html

They all seem to be img src tags as follows:

```
          <div class="tinyText"
               style="height: 129px; left: 97px; position: absolute; top: 158px; width: 215px; z-index: 1; ">
              <img usemap="#map1" 
                   id="shapeimage_1"
                   src="Calidus_files/shapeimage_1.png" style="border: none; height: 135px; left: -5px; position: absolute; top: -3px; width: 225px; z-index: 1; "
                  alt="Calidus" title="" />
              <map name="map1" id="map1">
                  <area href="Calidus_Profile.html"
                        title="Calidus_Profile.html" alt="Calidus_Profile.html"
                        coords="5, 3, 220, 132" />
              </map>
          </div>
```

Of course, there isn't a "tinyText" class in the css file. But when deleting the reference inside one of the div tags didn't make the image appear, either.

What's even stranger - the images appear in IE when I open the html file locally.

Can anyone give me a clue as to what might be going on?

Thanks,
Jason

Comment: Can you provide a SSCCE?

Comment: IE doesn't work good with negative positions

Answer (score 0):

After a semi-exhaustive search, I found someone claiming that IE doesn't like .png images. So I converted them all to .jpg format.

Images show up fine in IE9, so long as they're jpg's.

FYI

Comment: I was about to ask if you have cleared your browser cache? When I tested the site the images showed up fine. I wonder since you changed to JPGs they started showing up.